# Cache being halfway final

Tags: java, caching, static, global-variables

I have a small question i came up with reading this thread:
[Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)

In my application i have a really massive amount of lets say configuration variables. E.g. fonts, colors, cached images, ... As most of them never change i considered them being static.  Nevertheless my application is an applet and as the client has been executing the applet once, some of these static information may change, as a given configuration may have been changed. Therefore lets say this kind of data is used to change rarely, but is not considered being final.

In addition as the amount of information i handle that way is huge, i mapped them onto own Enums like that:

```
public enum Fonts {

    COLOR_CHOOSER, MAP_META_DATA; 
    private Font localFont;

    public Font getValue() {
        return localFont;
    }

    private void setValue(Font newFont) {
        localFont = newFont;
    }
}

protected static void initFonts() {
    Fonts.COLOR_CHOOSER.setValue(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    Fonts.MAP_META_DATA.setValue(font_race.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 11));
}
```

By using enums like that, I was able to identify the value I am looking for pretty easily, while i can maintain all of them at just one place.

Someone may say, since this is static, I could alternatively place them within the objects, they are used in anyway. Nevertheless, I considered the current behavior being more easy to read.

Besides of that the initFonts() method becomes replaced in future by a mapping method, which gets the currently hard coded values from an external source like json or xml. Therefore if i work OO this would mean to forward any of the incoming data to the corresponding objects, which I consider of being NOT easy to read.

To come up with my question:
How would somebody of you map/cache halfway final parameters (I also considered having a hashmap with an enum as key value). E.g for Images, Fonts, Colors, pixel margins, etc. Is the way i am using these enums appropriate or may I consider them being evil, since they are static? If yes - what would be an appropriate way, which keeps being easy to read and easy to maintain?!

I considered my solution of being a possible way to go, but were going to rethink the whole design after reading the above mentioned thread.

Thanks a lot for any advice.
Kind regards.

Comment: No comment by anybody ?!

Answer (score 0):

Enums are alright to represent static *final* data, which is why I don't think it's proper to have such an `initFonts()` method, modifying the content of the enum values, even if it's using a private method. What you should have is more like:

```
public enum Fonts {
    COLOR_CHOOSER(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15)),
    MAP_META_DATA(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 11)); // No reference to font_race, of course

    private final Font localFont;

    private Fonts(Font font) {
        localFont = font;
    }

    public Font getValue() {
        return localFont;
    }
}
```

I don't see why you say that your kind of configuration data is not final: it doesn't seem to change while the application is running.

However, if the runtime initialization needs to load values that may change, as opposed to being determined at compilation time, an enum may not be the correct model anymore, if it's unable to initialize its values itself in a simple manner (calling too much stuff from the static initializer of an enum might not be the best think to do). In that case, I'd replace the direct use of enums by an intermediate service, for example holding an immutable `Map<Fonts, Font>` (which might be an `EnumMap<Fonts, Font>` wrapped with `Collections.unmodifiableMap()`) initialized once and for all using the proper method, and instead of calling `Fonts.COLOR_CHOOSER.getValue()`, you'd call `FontService.getFont(Fonts.COLOR_CHOOSER)`.